# How to modify config file of spark job in Airflow UI?

Tags: apache-spark, airflow

I'm using Airflow to schedule for spark job and using a conf.properties file.
I want to change this file in Airflow UI not in server CLI.
How cant I do??

Comment: I dont think it is possible,
Airflow is a platform to programmatically author, schedule and monitor workflows.
When workflows are defined as code, they become more maintainable, versionable, testable, and collaborative.
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/index.html

If you need ETL / Integration tool that can be editted mostly on UI, have a look into Azure Data Factory then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Airflow webserver doesn't support files edit in its UI. But it allows you to add your plugins and customize the UI by adding `flask_appbuilder` views ([here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/plugins.html) is the doc).

You can also use an unofficial open source plugins to do that (ex: [airflow_code_editor](https://github.com/andreax79/airflow-code-editor)).